# SuppressMessage does not take MessageId into account for Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper, suppress-warnings

Take the code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2019).

```
public class Animal
{
    int age;
    string name;

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1500:VariableNamesShouldNotMatchFieldNames", MessageId = "age")]
    private void PrintInfo()
    {
        int age = 5;
        string name = "Charlie";

        Console.WriteLine($"Age {age}, Name {name}");
    }
}
```

The above example claims:

> To suppress a particular symbol violation of a rule, specify the symbol name for the MessageId property of the SuppressMessageAttribute attribute. The following example shows code with two violations of CA1500:VariableNamesShouldNotMatchFieldNames—one for the name variable and one for the age variable. Only the violation for the age symbol is suppressed.

My problem is that when using Resharper, the above `SuppressMessage` doesn't do anything. Instead I need to add `[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "LocalVariableHidesMember")]` and remove the Microsoft one. This will suppress everything. According to the documentation, adding `MessageId` should only suppress a single symbol so I tried to add this:

```
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "LocalVariableHidesMember", MessageId = "age")]
```

This however has the same effect. All symbols are suppressed. It looks like `MessageId` is not taken into account for Resharper.

I want to add that the example here is not a single case. `[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "AssignNullToNotNullAttribute"]` for example has the same problem.

Is there some way to resolve this or is this just Resharper?

Comment: Variables names shouldn't match fields names, i personally would take the advice. prefix them with `_` i.e `_age` or something, seems like less of a pain than suppressing messages

Comment: @MichaelRandall, I agree, but this isn't specifically for this violation. `[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "AssignNullToNotNullAttribute"]` has the same for example. (I've added it to the question.)

Comment: Why not just put `// ReSharper disable once ConvertToConstant.Local` on the line before each declaration?